# How to implement a xaml page for a generic-typed window/page for any type?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics, window

While it is easy to implement the xaml definition of a child window/page using x:TypeArguments, such as

```
// ParentWindowClass.cs
public abstract class ParentWindowClass<T> : Window { ... }

// ChildWindowClass
public class ChildWindowClass : ParentWindowClass<double> { ... }

<ParentWindowClass x:Class="MyNamespace.ChildWindowClass" x:TypeArguments="sys:Double">
```

How can we define the xaml code for a generic class if we want to allow any type to be used as type parameter? For example:

```
// GenericDialog.xaml.cs
public partial class GenericDialog<T> : Window
{
    T SomePublicProperty { get; }

    public GenericDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
        // (This is because x:Class is incomplete in the xaml file)
    }
}

<!-- GenericDialog.xaml -->
<Window x:class="MyNamespace.GenericDialog">
<!-- x:TypeArguments doesn't apply here because it can be used for any type -->
```

The end goal is the following use cases that all reuse the same xaml:

```
new GenericDialog<int>().Show()
new GenericDialog<DateTime>().Show()
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: The usual errors when the x:Class is wrong or incomplete. I will add them to the question..

Comment: Are you talking about using the code-behind as a class?  I don't think that is supported because it has to be bound to a single xaml file.
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1580

Comment: No that's not what I'm saying. I'm using Desktop WPF not Xamarin Forms. I want to be able to call `new GenericDialog<int>().Show()` or `new GenericDialog<DateTime>().Show()`. It's all a very standard usage except for the generic part. I will add more detail in the question again to avoid confusion.